# python selenium + geckodriver in docker container with headless mode cannot scroll page

Tags: python, selenium, docker, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to run selenium with geckodriver in headless mode in a docker container ubuntu 18.04. This is my code:

```
    while True:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        time.sleep(2)
        newHeight = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        print('scrolling..')
        if newHeight == lastHeight:
            print(f'scrolling done..')
            list_of_images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('._2eea a')
            print(f'collecting: {fp_url}')
            images = []
            for image in list_of_images:
                url = image.get_attribute('href')
                if 'type=3' in str(url):
                    print(f'append: {url}')
                    images.append(url)
                    # clear_memory()
            print(f'total: {len(images)} memes')
            count = 1
        else:
            lastHeight = newHeight
```

i got no error when i tried in my local computer but when i tried in a docker container it seems like the page wont scroll. And this is my driver setup:

```
    options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
    options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('-headless')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "geckodriver"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your chrome driver is completely up to date, but worth checking

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

perhaps trying a few different ways of scrolling could yield some better results :)

Using actions chains - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains as AC

ele = driver.find_element_by_id("myID")

actions = AC(driver)
actions.move_to_element(ele).perform()
```

Passing element id as argument into scrollintoview()

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", ele)
```